# When were the first jet engines used?

Tags: jet-engine

I read a book about WW2 <sup>1</sup> and saw a couple of planes with a giant jet engine on top of them, e.g. the [Heinkel He 162 Salamander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinkel_He_162).

I realize jet engines had to have been invented before WW2 for that kind of technology to be used, so when were the first aircraft jet engines around?

*<sup>1</sup> Aircraft of World War II: 300 of the World's Greatest Aircraft. Chris Chant.*

Comment: You can find this book at barnes and nobles.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_engine

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first *aircraft* jet engine was ground tested by Frank Whittle in April 1937. In September of the same year, Hans von Ohain (ground) tested his jet engine.

The first jet aircraft, He 178 flew in August 1939.

Comment: What are your references? Fact checking and further reading is nice.

Comment: See http://inventors.about.com/library/inventors/bljetengine.htm and http://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/courses/ww2/projects/jet-airplanes/planes.html. This information is available in Wikipedia too (See the comment on the question by Simon).

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coand%C4%83-1910):

> In 2010, based on the notion that Coandă invented the first jet, the
>   centennial of the jet aircraft was celebrated in Romania.

[image]

This aircraft was built by Henri Coandă, he of the effect that the [NOTAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOTAR) helicopter is based on. It was part of an aviation exposition in Paris, in 1910. Claims that it has actually flown are disputed, but not everywhere in the world apparently. The engine was a 50 hp piston engine driving a cowled fan.